# Databound Combobox is giving me empty fields?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I've got a vb.net ComboBox that is databound to a table in an Oracle database. The oracle database fills a dataset that is defined in my solution. I have a few comboboxes in one of my views that are databound to seperate datasets. They all work correctly except for one. One of them brings back 80 rows of data as expected, but there is no text in the combobox. So you are just searching through 80 rows of nothing. Here's the code:

```
    Dim dsLegalEntity As New DataSet
    Dim dsTaxCertification As New DataSet
    Dim dsStates As New DataSet
    Dim mdataviewLegalEntity As New DataView
    Dim mdataviewTaxCertification As New DataView
    Dim mdataviewStates As New DataView

    Try

        dsLegalEntity = My.WebServices.Service.GetLegalEntities()
        mdataviewLegalEntity = New DataView(dsLegalEntity.Tables("AS_LEGAL_ENTITIES"))

        dsTaxCertification = My.WebServices.Service.GetTaxCertCodes
        mdataviewTaxCertification = New DataView(dsTaxCertification.Tables("TAX_CERT_CODE"))

        dsStates = My.WebServices.Service.GetVendorStates
        mdataviewStates = New DataView(dsStates.Tables("VENDOR_STATES"))

        With comboLegalEntity
            .DataSource = mdataviewLegalEntity
            .ValueMember = "LEGAL_ENTITY"
            .DisplayMember = "LEGAL_ENTITY"
        End With

        With comboTaxCertification
            .DataSource = mdataviewTaxCertification
            .ValueMember = "TAX_CERT_CODE"
            .DisplayMember = "TAX_CERT_CODE_DESCR"
        End With

        With comboState
            .DataSource = mdataviewStates
            .ValueMember = "STATE"
            .DisplayMember = "STATE"
        End With

        comboPurchSale.SelectedIndex = 0
    Catch ex As Exception
        AppError.InsertAppError(ex.ToString(), "btnQSearch_Click", "Default.aspx", "")
    End Try
```

The combobox that is the problem is the "comboState" one. The dataset table name is called "VENDOR_STATES" and the column it points to is called "STATE". As far as I can tell, I have my names right, so I don't understand why this one won't work correctly while the others work fine. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Use the debugger to see what is inside `mdataviewStates`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was resolved. It turns out the dataset column and column name returned from the stored procedure must match in order for the data to go through correctly. After adding a SELECT AS STATE to my stored procedure select statement, it worked perfectly.